# How to split a sting into groups where the regular expression is true

Tags: regex, ruby

I am I'm getting an equation(polynomial) as a string and I'm trying to use a regular expression to split the equation into groups where the expression is true.

What I have so far:

```
>>> str = "13x^14-12x^3+x^3-11"
>>> puts str.split(/[+-]?\d*x?\^?\d*/)
["13x^14-12x^3+x^3-11"]
```

What I'm trying to get:
`["13x^14","-12x^3","+x^3","-11"]`

How my expression works

- [+-]?   : + or - can exist 0 or 1 time
- \d*     : the numbers 0-9 can appear 0 to an infinite amount of times
- x?      : x can appear 0 or 1 time
- ^?     : the character ^ can appear 0 or 1 time
- \d*     : the numbers 0-9 can appear 0 to an infinite amount of times

Comment: remove `^` and `$` from start and end of your pattern: `[+-]?\d*x?\^?\d*`

Comment: If I remove the `^` and `$` an empty array is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using split, you can match all the occurrences and omit the anchors `^` and `$`

As all your matches end on a digit, you can change the last parts to match at least 1 or more digits `\d+` to prevent empty matches as all the parts are optional.

```
str = '13x^14-12x^3+x^3-11'

str.scan(/[+-]?\d*x?\^?\d+/) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

Output

```
13x^14
-12x^3
+x^3
-11
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a regular expression and you put the delimiter inside of a group, split will capture the delimiter as well. [Source](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-regex-tricks/)

```rb
str.split(/([+-]?\d*x?\^?\d*)/) - [""]
```

Comment: This still returned a empty list

Answer (score 0):

If you use gsub to replace the + and - symbol with "|+" and "|-" then you can use `split("|")` to get that information. You don't need the regular expression to split the string.

```
str = "13x^14-12x^3+x^3-11"
str.gsub(/[+]/,"|").gsub(/[-]/,"|-").split("|")
["13x^14","-12x^3","x^3","-11"]
```